# Select random and remove AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, random

I have this project at school. We're going to create an application, that picks out 7 random numbers, between 1-34, no repeat numbers, sorts them and display them in a textbox. And i have no idea where to start.

Comment: Your question is too generic (and I suspect it will get closed for this reason unless you update it). What are you having trouble with? Generating randoms? Ensuring that they are unique? Sorting them? Displaying them?

Answer (score 1):

For generating Numbers you will need Math.random, for sorting Array.sort, for displaying TextField:

```
var len:uint = 7;
var min:uint = 1;
var max:uint = 34;
var filled:uint;
var result:Array = [];
var random:int;

//Filling collection with random numbers
while (filled < len) {
    random = min + Math.random() * (max - min);
    if (result.indexOf(random) == -1) {
        result.push(random);
        filled++;
    }
}

//Sorting your collection, don't read further, if you want to do something yourself ;)
result.sort(Array.NUMERIC);

//Display result
var textField:TextField = new TextField();
textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
textField.text = result.toString();
addChild(textField);
```

One of results:

```
 1,8,13,16,20,26,32
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to do this. The fastest way to fill a unique array of random numbers is to fill the array with the number range, in your case that would be an array from 1-34, then set a max variable to the length of your array - 1 (for the last index of the array). Then implement a while loop while your max variable is greater than 0 `( while( max > 0 ) )`, swap a random index of your array with your current max position. I understand that may sound confusing so here is an example:

```
//create our array of numbers, you could do this in a for loop or 
//set it as I have ( which saves you some performance )
var numbers = [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34 ];

var max:int = numbers.length-1; //set our max to the array length - 1
var randomIndex:int; //create the randomIndex variable
while( max > 0 ) {
    randomIndex = Math.random() * max; //pick a random index
    numbers[randomIndex] ^= numbers[max]; //swap the random index with our max
    numbers[max] ^= numbers[randomIndex];
    numbers[randomIndex] ^= numbers[max];
    max--; //decrease the max
}
numbers.length = 7; //set array length to 7 elements so you have 7 random numbers
```

What this does is it guarantees that every element of the array is both unique and gets swapped.

This is the fastest and arguably the easiest way to randomly generate a unique set of numbers within a certain range. It's also known as a [Fisher Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) 
.

Then you can sort your array numerically using: `numbers.sort( Array.NUMERIC )`

Lastly to add it to a `TextField`, you create a new `TextField` and use the `text` property set to your array value in `String` format:

```
var textField:TextField = new TextField();
textField.text = numbers.toString();
addChild( textField );
```

Here is some documentation about `TextFields` to help you learn:

[TextField AS3.0](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html)

Answer (score 0):

place this function at anywhere

```
function getRandomNum(startNum, endNum, totalNumberGet):Array{
    var numbersArray:Array = [];
    var return:Array = [];

    for(var i:int = startNum; i <= endNum; i++){
        numbersArray.push(i);
    }
    for(var ii:int = 0; ii < totalNumberGet; ii++){
        var random:int = Math.random() * numbersArray.length;
        return.push(numbersArray[ii]);
        numbersArray.splice(ii,1);
    }
    result.sort(Array.NUMERIC);
    return result;
}
```

to run it, call `var myResult:Array = getRandomNum(1,43,7);`